# Check if user input is a valid date

Tags: c#, date, tryparse

I am building a calendar and I want to check if the user input is a valid date. I got this far and now I dont' know how to repeat the message "invalid date" until it's a valid one.

---

My code:

```
var dateFormats = new[] {"dd.MM.yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy"};

Console.Write("\nSet your date: ");

string readAddMeeting = Console.ReadLine();
DateTime scheduleDate;

bool validDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(
    readAddMeeting,
    dateFormats,
    DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo,
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out scheduleDate);

if (validDate)
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    Console.WriteLine("Valid date");
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
}
else
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine("Invalid date: \"{0}\"", readAddMeeting);
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
}
```

Comment: You can use `while` statement. Check it's documentation.

Comment: you need to explain what you mean by, " how to repeat the message "invalid date" until its a valid one" I don't follow.

Comment: You can use while. AND you don't need to have dateformats, along with TryParseExact. Instead you could simply use TryParse. For example, if current culture is en-US then user might want to input "Jan 1st, 2015" which IS a valid date.

Comment: you need to use a while statement... didnt see it was a console app, "Console.ReadLine()"

Comment: Correction to my comment, .Net framework is not clever enough to see Jan 1st, 2015 is a valid date. Jan 1, 2015 is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like:

```
var dateFormats = new[] {"dd.MM.yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy"};

bool validate = true;
while (validate) // Loop indefinitely
{
    Console.Write("\nSet your date: "); // Prompt
    string readAddMeeting = Console.ReadLine(); // Get string from user

    DateTime scheduleDate;
    if(DateTime.TryParseExact(readAddMeeting,dateFormats, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out scheduleDate))
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
        Console.WriteLine("Valid date");
        validate = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid date: \"{0}\"", readAddMeeting);
    }
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
}
```

Comment: When you write `while (true)` it always shows "enter valid date" even if you write one.

Comment: so what the working soloutin? I am trying for long time now. No clue how it works 100%.

Comment: @user5462581 the 100% was you are 100% correct! I have updated since that comment. Thanks

Comment: What? I don't get it. It's still repeating indefinitely. I want to repeat the message "Input a valid date" **until** the user entered a valid date.

Comment: @user5462581 there must be more to the story just tested this myself, and it works. take it as is and put it in a new console main.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `do/while` loop:

```
do
{
      ... your code here

}while(!validDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a do-While loop:

```
do{
var dateFormats = new[] {"dd.MM.yyyy", "dd-MM-yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy"};

Console.Write("\nSet your date: ");

string readAddMeeting = Console.ReadLine();
DateTime scheduleDate;

bool validDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(
readAddMeeting,
dateFormats,
DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo,
DateTimeStyles.None,
out scheduleDate);

if (validDate)
{
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.WriteLine("Valid date");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
}
else
{
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
Console.WriteLine("Invalid date: \"{0}\"", readAddMeeting);
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
}
}while(!validDate)
```